# Adding export option to Office 2010 backstage view

Tags: ribbon, office-2010, office-addins

I cannot extend Office 2010 UI even when I use the code from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee815851.aspx). This is the code I think should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
  <backstage>
    <tab idMso="TabShare">
      <firstColumn>
        <taskFormGroup idMso="GroupShare">
          <category idMso="FileTypes">
            <task id="tskExportXmlCms" label="Exportovat jako XML">
              <group id="grpExportXmlCms" label="Exportovat jako XML">
                <topItems>
                  <button id="btnExportXmlCms" label="Exportovat jako XML" onAction="OnExportXmlCms" />
                </topItems>
              </group>
            </task>
          </category>
        </taskFormGroup>
      </firstColumn>
    </tab>
  </backstage>
</customUI>

public void OnExportXmlCms(IRibbonControl control) { }
```

When I add *Ribbon (Visual Designer)* I can see added items. When I use *Ribbin (XML)* I'm not able to see anything in the backstage. What is wrong?

Comment: Is `OnExportXmlCms` a typo? It doesn't look like it should be part of the customUI XML... :)

Comment: If I paste your XML into a blank Word 2010 document using the [Custom UI Editor](http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2006/05/25/customuieditor.aspx), there is a new button in the _Save & Send_ tab in the backstage view which calls `btnExportXmlCms`, just as intended. In other word, the XML itself is not the problem. Are there any differences between the _Ribbon (Visual Designer)_ and _Ribbon (XML)_ you can see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was missing this method:

```
public partial class ThisAddIn {
    protected override Office.IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject() {
        return new Ribbon();
    }
}
```